# How can I add multiple Strings(items) to a single PopupMenu list

Tags: android, popupmenu

I am trying to add multiple strings to one single **PopUpMenu** list item but I couldn't find a method that would allow me to add multiple strings or a way around it.Is there a way to achieve this? After I add the items, I want them to be individually clickable as well, just like how a single list item would respond to its click.Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: create custom menu adapter. See here - https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/create-options-menu-recyclerview-item-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks Tauqir for the answer but this shows how you can attach a menu to a recyclerview, not how you can add multiple items to a single menu item.

Comment: The link is for more details. Any how, you need to create custom layout or adapter (which ever works for you) and use it inside menu. Custom menu makes your requirement feasible.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the custom layout option you suggested.

Comment: I tried using a custom layout but within the menu tag, It only allows me to add "<item>" tags vertically, is there a way i can add these tags horizontally?